# Filter method does not return resutls

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've been working on a project to create Chatter group members when a checkbox is checked on the user record. I have this method that runs on beforeUpdate to check if the checkbox has been checked.

```
public static Set<Id> filterUpdate(Map<Id, User> newMap)
{
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();

    // Check if the user is active and the Add to Chatter Group is checked
    for(User u : newMap.values())
    {
        if(
            u.Add_To_Chatter_Group__c == TRUE &&
            u.IsActive == TRUE
        )
            {
                userIds.add(u.Id);
            }
    }
    if(userIds.size() > 0)
    {
        return userIds;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

With help I have created this test method to check if the above method returns a result. The assert fails because the actual (results) is null. This doesn't make sense to me as the filter is checkbox = true checkbox = true and in the debug the checkboxes are indeed true. What am I missing to get this to work?

```
static Integer dummyIdCount = 0;
static final String USER_PREFIX = SobjectType.user.getKeyPrefix();
static Id getdummyID()
{
    return USER_PREFIX + String.valueOf(dummyIdCount++).leftPad(15, '0');
}

@isTest static void testUpdateFilter_HappyPath()
{
    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        users.put(getDummyId(), new User(IsActive = TRUE, Add_To_Chatter_Group__c = TRUE));

    System.debug('Users is:: ' + users);

    Test.startTest();
        Set<Id> results = SL_UserTriggerHandler.filterUpdate(users);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.debug('Results is:: ' + results);

    system.assertEquals(users.keySet(), results,
        'Each record should be returned');
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't return a null value just because the Set is empty. This unnecessarily complicates code that depends on this method.

Comment: If I drop it I get "Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement." So I think it has to be there?

Comment: You can skip the if-then part, just `return userIds;` is sufficient.

Comment: ahh got it, I think I was trying to keep it from going to the @future method I have later on if there were no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the below code you are just creating in-memory user records and these user records don't have Id.

```
users.put(getDummyId(), new User(IsActive = TRUE, Add_To_Chatter_Group__c = TRUE));
```

But `filterUpdate` method is trying to get Id of each user as below:

```
userIds.add(u.Id); //If you debug this u.Id will be NULL.
```

Add this line

```
insert users.values(); // this will generate Id for each user record in the map.
```

before calling the `filterUpdate` method and try.

**Workaround which does not involve inserting user records:**

change your for loop as below:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  Id tempId = getDummyId();
  users.put(tempId, new User(IsActive = TRUE, Add_To_Chatter_Group__c = TRUE,Id = tempId));
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57288/discussion-on-answer-by-javanoob-filter-method-does-not-return-resutls).